# Using REST at web

Tags: rest

What is ***REST*** when using in WEB ?

Too many documentations, but is it just a simple attitude using existing html protocol, that may replace web-services.

Is it as following?

Like ***PAYPAL*** ...

Just using method from a specific server using http protocol: https://?

and on the server side using the value by get/post methods.

Entities:

Clients - every client that has access to server A (for the specific service).

Server A - Server (for the client use) that has an access to server (with an access key, like PAYPAL supports).

Server B - Server that has the API with some methods that returns to client.

Steps:

```
1. User ask from server A (server A uses the API) for a token.
2. Server A open a session with server B and send request for token (with the access key provided) to server B
3. Server B may reject or accept the request and send back the token to server A.
4. Server A may keep the token in session variable and send the token to the client.
5. Client use the token
6. Client send requests to server A, that send requests to server B with the token, keeping the same session.
```

Is the above correct?

Is that the concept of REST?

If not - need some guidelines, please.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the concept of tokens is beyond the REST concept.

Rest (Representational state transfer) has more to do with the way you use the http methods to represent your desired action, like going to /users with get should give you back an arrays of users, then post in /users/1234 should create a user with id 1234 for example, or delete in /users/1234 should delete the user with 1234 id, etc.

It is an architecture where the http methods have a meaning.

Anyway there are more details of it, I would continue to read more with below;

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer